# CORBA IDL precompiler for C++

Tags: c++, corba, idl

My teacher has told us to do an application in which we use CORBA for communicating a C++ server with a Java client. I can do it with the following OS's, in order of preference:

-Windows 7

-Windows 8

-Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander

Any recommendations on the IDL precompiler for C++?

Comment: Maybe ask your teacher...

Comment: The IDL compiler should be shipped with your ORB, such as [omniORB](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [omniORB](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/), that comes with IDL compiler. It is open source library for C++ and Python. For the Java side I could suggest [jacORB](http://www.jacorb.org/)

Comment: Other options are TAO (see http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu) or TAOX11 (see http://swsupport.remedy.nl). TAOX11 is supporting the new IDL to C++11 Language Mapping which is way easier to use than the C++ mapping. At this moment it only has evaluation packages (which can be used for educational purposes) for Linux, Windows packages are coming soon. For Java, definitively go for JacORB.